# Spring boot dependency injection not working for subclasses, value not initialized on invocation

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin, inheritance, dependency-injection

I'm wanting to inject som dependencies to some of the subclasses in my project, however it's not working how I imagined... I'm using **Spring Boot 3.0.4** and **Java 17** written in **Kotlin 1.8.0**

My classes looks as follows:

```
@Service
sealed class Integration {

  @Autowired lateinit var smsClient: SmsClient

  @Autowired lateinit var emailClient: EmailClient

  abstract val reference: UUID
  abstract val integrationType: IntegrationType
  abstract fun send(incomingMessage: String)
  abstract fun getContactPoints(): List<String>
}

@Schema(description = "Integration of sms notifications.", allOf = [Integration::class])
class SmsIntegration(
    override val reference: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    override val integrationType: IntegrationType = IntegrationType.SMS_INTEGRATION,
    val countryCode: String,
    val phoneNumbers: List<String>,
) : Integration() {

  @PostConstruct
  override fun send(incomingMessage: String) {
    phoneNumbers.forEach { smsClient.postSms(SmsRequest(countryCode, it, incomingMessage)) }
  }
  override fun getContactPoints(): List<String> = this.phoneNumbers

  fun copy(phoneNumbers: List<String>): SmsIntegration =
      SmsIntegration(
          reference = this.reference, countryCode = this.countryCode, phoneNumbers = phoneNumbers)
}

@Schema(description = "Integration of email notifications.", allOf = [Integration::class])
class EmailIntegration(
    override val reference: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    override val integrationType: IntegrationType = IntegrationType.EMAIL_INTEGRATION,
    val emails: List<String>,
    val subject: String,
) : Integration() {

  @PostConstruct
  override fun send(incomingMessage: String) {
    val emailAddresses: List<EmailAddress> = emails.map { EmailAddress(email = it) }
    val email =
        Email(
            from = EmailAddress(email = "test@test.org"),
            to = emailAddresses,
            subject = subject,
            body = incomingMessage)

    emailClient.sendEmail(email)
  }
  override fun getContactPoints(): List<String> = this.emails

  fun copy(emails: List<String>): EmailIntegration =
      EmailIntegration(reference = this.reference, subject = this.subject, emails = emails)
}

@Schema(description = "Integration of slack notifications.", allOf = [Integration::class])
class SlackIntegration(
    override val reference: UUID = UUID.randomUUID(),
    override val integrationType: IntegrationType = IntegrationType.SLACK_INTEGRATION,
    val channelIds: List<String>
) : Integration() {

  fun copy(channelIds: List<String>): SlackIntegration =
      SlackIntegration(reference = this.reference, channelIds = channelIds)

  @PostConstruct
  override fun send(incomingMessage: String) {
    channelIds.forEach { SlackBot.sendMessage(channelId = it, message = incomingMessage) }
  }

  override fun getContactPoints(): List<String> = this.channelIds
}
```

As you can see, I have two autowired clients, one for sms and one for email, in my *Integration* class. I would rather want them in the individual classes, however I don't want to pass emailClients and smsclients in constructors around the code when creating these classes, so I opted to put them in the *Integration* class. However they're not initialized when calling the **send()** function in *SmsIntegration* and *EmailIntegration* classes.

I feel like I've structured my code in a bad way with regards to dependency injection in spring boot. It was nice and easy with only the *slackBot* because it is a singleton, but with the added dependencies it made it a mess..

Any help restructuring or making this work is appreciated.

Comment: `@PostConstruct` won't work on a method with arguments. You have 3 instances and although they are subclasses that doesn't mean they inherit the injected dependencies (they are still separate instances).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about `@Schema` annotation,
i assume it makes your classes component

when you are doing inheritance and Autowired, make sure to set the annotation on setter with `@set:Autowired`, you don't even need to mark your super class with service in this case,

i think it's a bad idea to aquire implementations in superclass, and as mentioned in comments `@PostConstruct` is not to meant be for this (i think you want to use `@EventListener` in this case)

here is another approach :

```kotlin
// Integration.kt
interface Message
interface Integration {
    fun send(message: Message)
    fun supports(message: Message): Boolean
}

// SMSIntegration.kt
class SMS(val phoneNumber: String) : Message
@Service
class IntegrationSMS : Integration {
    override fun send(message: Message) {
        message as SMS
        // send it
    }

    // implements send(SMS)
    override fun supports(message: Message) = message is SMS
}

// SlackIntegration.kt
class SlackMessage : Message
@Service
class IntegrationSlack : Integration {
    override fun send(message: Message) {
        message as SlackMessage
    }

    // implements send(SlackMessage)
    override fun supports(message: Message) = message is SlackMessage
}


// IntegrationManager.kt
@Service
class IntegrationManager(@Autowired  val integrators: List<Integration> ){

   @EventListener
   fun sendMessage(message: Message){
       for(integration in integrators)
          if(integration.supports(message)
             integration.send(message)
   }

}
```

now anywhere in your code you can do:

```kotlin
@Service
class SomewhereElse( val publisher: ApplicationEventPublisher){

   fun doSomethingAndSendSMS(){
     ... 
     publisher.publish(SMS("1234"))
   }

   fun doSomethingAndSendSlackMessage(){
     ... 
     publisher.publish(SlackMessage())
   }

}
```

if you put aside the `@EventListener` you can call `IntegrationManager.sendMessage` directly this is the actual approach SpringSecurity uses (as far as i know in servlet) with `AuthenticationProvider` and `AuthenticationManager` and several `AuthenticationTokens`